# Rebase versus Delivery

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

After going to production, they want to update the `Dev` and `INT` streams with the current `Prod` Code.

Should I deliver (interproject) to `Dev` streams and then deliver up to `Integration` or deliver to `Integration` and then rebase to `Dev`?

We have a `Maintenance-HotFix` and two `Dev` streams for different releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a "prod" code, it is best to deliver to `INT`, and then rebase to `Dev`.

That way, the new foundation baseline (ie the new "`prod`" baseline) will be clearly visible on the `Dev` stream (because that is what a rebase does: changing the foundation baseline).